# Kivy screen background doesn't load during screen switching

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently working on my first application using kivy (a simple timer / notekeeping app for studying). Recently I ran into a small issue. Even though it was working just fine a few days ago, now the background on my "TimerScreen" is slow to load. When I switch from the "ScheduleScreen" back to the "TimerScreen", **the background is temporarily black until the switching transition is completely over**. Switching from the "GraphScreen" (which for now is just a button) back to the "TimerScreen" does not have the same problem and the background is there for the entire transition. I cleared up the "SceduleScreen" from all the labels and textinput boxes thinking maybe it was too loaded, as it was a messy design, but the issue was still there.
**Furthermore, that only happens when I run the application on my phone using the kivy app, and not on my computer.**
I would like to make the transition happen with the background image already loaded, for a smoother feel and look. Here is my code (sorry if the code is pretty messy, any questions or suggestions are welcome. Also, **I had a little bit of trouble pasting the code into this question and some of the whitespace will be off**, but its not the case on my actual code).

```
Builder.load_string("""

<ScheduleScreen>:


    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            source: 'background4.jpg'

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 9

        Label:
            text: "Schedule"
            font_size: '20sp'
            size: dp(100), dp(50)
            size_hint: None, None 

        Label:
            text: "Subject/Hours"
            font_size: '20sp'
            size: dp(100), dp(50)
            size_hint: None, None 



        Label:
            text: "Monday"

        TextInput: 
            id: box1
            multiline: False
            font_size: '17sp'
            size: dp(250), dp(70)
            size_hint: None, None





        Label:
            text: "Tuesday"

        TextInput:     
            id: box2
            multiline: False
            font_size: '17sp'
            size: dp(250), dp(70)
            size_hint: None, None




        Label:
            text: "Wednesday"

        TextInput:     
            id: box3
            multiline: False
            font_size: '17sp'
            size: dp(250), dp(70)
            size_hint: None, None




        Label:
            text: "Thursday"

        TextInput: 
            id: box4    
            multiline: False
            font_size: '17sp'
            size: dp(250), dp(70)
            size_hint: None, None



        Label:
            text: "Friday"

        TextInput:  
            id: box5   
            multiline: False
            font_size: '17sp'
            size: dp(250), dp(70)
            size_hint: None, None





        Label:
            text: "Saturday"

        TextInput:  
            id: box6   
            multiline: False
            font_size: '17sp'
            size: dp(250), dp(70)
            size_hint: None, None




        Label:
            text: "Sunday"

        TextInput:  
            id: box7  
            multiline: False
            font_size: '17sp'
            size: dp(250), dp(70)
            size_hint: None, None




        Button:
            size: dp(100), dp(100)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .85, 'center_y': .1}
            size_hint: None, None
            background_normal: 'button1flip.png'
            background_down: 'button1flipdark.png'
            on_press: 
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.current = 'timerscreen'




        Button:
            text: "Save"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            font_size: '16sp'
            size: dp(100), dp(100)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .15, 'center_y': .1}
            size_hint: None, None
            background_normal: 'button4.png'
            background_down: 'button4dark.png'
            on_press: root.SaveNotes()




<GraphScreen>:
    BoxLayout:    
        Button:
            text: 'goto main'
            on_press: 
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'timerscreen'



   <TimerScreen>:

canvas.before:
    Rectangle:
        size: self.size
        source: 'background4.jpg'


label_wid: my_custom_label

BoxLayout:
    rows: 2

    orientation: 'vertical'


    Label:
        pos: dp(100), dp(100)
        font_size: '40sp'
        id: my_custom_label
        text: 'timer!'

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id: startbutton
            size: dp(250), dp(140)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}
            size_hint: None, None
            text: root.buttonstatus
            font_size: '17sp'
            color: 0,0,0,1
            background_normal: 'button4.png'
            background_down: 'button4dark.png'
            on_press: root.startUpdating()


        Button:
            id: resetbutton
            size: dp(150), dp(100)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.0}
            size_hint: None,None
            text: "reset timer"
            font_size: '15sp'
            color: 0,0,0,1
            background_normal: 'button4.png'
            background_down: 'button4dark.png'
            on_press:
                root.resettimer()

    FloatLayout:
        cols: 2

        Button:
            size: dp(100), dp(100)
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.8, 'center_y': 0.3}
            background_normal: 'button1.png'
            background_down: 'button1dark.png'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.manager.current = "schedulescreen"


        Button:
            size: dp(100), dp(100)
            size_hint: None,None
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.2, 'center_y': 0.3}
            text: "Progress"
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.manager.current = "graphscreen"

""")


sound = SoundLoader.load('ring.wav')



class ScheduleScreen(Screen):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    try:

        pickle_in1 = open("mon_notes.pickle", "rb")
        pickle_in2 = open("tue_notes.pickle", "rb")
        pickle_in3 = open("wed_notes.pickle", "rb")
        pickle_in4 = open("thu_notes.pickle", "rb")                 # open pickle note files
        pickle_in5 = open("fri_notes.pickle", "rb")
        pickle_in6 = open("sat_notes.pickle", "rb")
        pickle_in7 = open("sun_notes.pickle", "rb")


        self.ids.box1.text = pickle.load(pickle_in1)
        self.ids.box2.text = pickle.load(pickle_in2)
        self.ids.box3.text = pickle.load(pickle_in3)
        self.ids.box4.text = pickle.load(pickle_in4)                # load the text into the textboxes
        self.ids.box5.text = pickle.load(pickle_in5)    
        self.ids.box6.text = pickle.load(pickle_in6)
        self.ids.box7.text = pickle.load(pickle_in7)    

    except:
        self.ids.box1.text = "You can keep your notes here!"

def SaveNotes(self):

    mon_notes = self.ids.box1.text    
    tue_notes = self.ids.box2.text
    wed_notes = self.ids.box3.text
    thu_notes = self.ids.box4.text
    fri_notes = self.ids.box5.text              
    sat_notes = self.ids.box6.text
    sun_notes = self.ids.box7.text

    pickle_out1 = open("mon_notes.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(mon_notes, pickle_out1)
    pickle_out1.close

    pickle_out2 = open("tue_notes.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(tue_notes, pickle_out2)
    pickle_out2.close

    pickle_out3 = open("wed_notes.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(wed_notes, pickle_out3)
    pickle_out3.close

    pickle_out4 = open("thu_notes.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(thu_notes, pickle_out4)
    pickle_out4.close

    pickle_out5 = open("fri_notes.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(fri_notes, pickle_out5)
    pickle_out5.close

    pickle_out6 = open("sat_notes.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(sat_notes, pickle_out6)
    pickle_out6.close

    pickle_out7 = open("sun_notes.pickle", "wb")
    pickle.dump(sun_notes, pickle_out7)
    pickle_out7.close







class GraphScreen(Screen):
pass





class TimerScreen(Screen):  #FloatLayout):
global sound
sessionlength = 1500                      #  <==== 25 mins set timer
breaklength = 300                          #  <==== 5 mins set timer
buttonstatus = "Press to start"
started = False
paused = False
studyStatus = "study"
timecount = sessionlength                             
totaltime = 0

label_wid = ObjectProperty()

event1 = ObjectProperty()

def MyClock(self, timecount):

    self.label_wid.text = "Mins: " + str(self.timecount // 60) + " , secs: " + str(self.timecount % 60)
    self.timecount -= 1
    #self.totaltime += 1

    if self.timecount == -1:
        sound.play()
        if self.studyStatus == "study":   
            self.studyStatus = "break"                       # timecount is 1 sec ahead of text
            self.label_wid.text = "Break time!"
            self.timecount = self.breaklength
            Clock.unschedule(self.event1)
            self.buttonstatus = "start"
            self.ids.startbutton.text = self.buttonstatus
            self.started = False

        elif self.studyStatus == "break":
            self.studyStatus = "study"
            self.label_wid.text = "Back to studying"
            self.timecount = self.sessionlength
            Clock.unschedule(self.event1)
            self.buttonstatus = "start"
            self.ids.startbutton.text = self.buttonstatus
            self.started = False





def startUpdating(self):
    if not self.started:
        self.event1 = Clock.schedule_interval(self.MyClock, 1)
        self.buttonstatus = "pause"
        self.ids.startbutton.text = self.buttonstatus
        self.started = True
    else:
        Clock.unschedule(self.event1)
        self.started = False

        if self.timecount != 0:
            self.buttonstatus = "resume"

        self.ids.startbutton.text = self.buttonstatus


def resettimer(self):
    Clock.unschedule(self.event1)
    self.started = False
    if self.studyStatus == "study":
        self.timecount = self.sessionlength
    elif self.studyStatus == "break":
        self.timecount = self.breaklength

    self.label_wid.text = "Mins: " + str(self.timecount // 60) + " , secs: " + str(self.timecount % 60)
    self.buttonstatus = "start"
    self.ids.startbutton.text = self.buttonstatus




sm = ScreenManager()

sm.add_widget(ScheduleScreen(name = 'schedulescreen'))
sm.add_widget(GraphScreen(name = 'graphscreen'))
sm.add_widget(TimerScreen(name = 'timerscreen'))

sm.current = "timerscreen"




class TimerApp(App):

def build(self):
    return sm



if __name__ == "__main__":
TimerApp().run()
```

Comment: Can you post a much more minimal example? It would be useful to be able to reproduce with as little code as possible.

Comment: After simplifying and cleaning up the code to re-post it, I found out this. Long story short, the 'save' button seems to be causing this, because whenever I remove its block of code my issue is fixed( The problem looks to be in the kv part of the code and not the actual save function of my screen's class). Being an integral part of my application's functionality, I would appreciate it if someone helped me to find exactly what causes this, or a different way to go about it. The kv code for the button:

Comment: Button:
            text: "Save"
            color: 0,0,0,1
            font_size: '16sp'
            size: dp(100), dp(100)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .15, 'center_y': .1}
            size_hint: None, None
            background_normal: 'button4.png'
            background_down: 'button4dark.png'
            on_press: root.SaveNotes()`